# Interpolating geographically weighted regression (GWR) - fit to raster?

Tags: raster, r, interpolation, geographically-weighted-regression

Using the spgwr package I followed [this tutorial](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/44975_0342ec49f925426fa16ebcdc28210118.html) and found [a way](http://geokitchen.blogspot.co.at/2012_09_01_archive.html) to interpolate the result to a raster layer (gwr on  pixel/raster  data using the meuse data set, further down the script). But the second step is taking hour by hour and I am not sure if R is hanging or if the code is wrong.

Here is what I did until now:

```
# calculating the bandwidth     
bw<- gwr.sel(pb_train ~ gesteine + schnee_tag_1 + rs_hospso, data=env.spdf, adapt=FALSE)

# running first gwr model
fGo<- gwr(pb_train ~ gesteine + schnee_tag_1 + rs_hospso, env.spdf, bandwidth=bw, hatmatrix=TRUE)

spplot(fGo$SDF, "pred")
```

[image]

This is where R keeps hanging...

```
gwr.priclus<- gwr(pb_train ~ gesteine + schnee_tag_1 + rs_hospso, env.spdf, bandwidth=bw, fit.points=env.grid, predict=TRUE, se.fit=TRUE, fittedGWRobject = fGo)
```

`env.spdf` is a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` with my predictors at each location. `env.grid` is a `SpatialPixelsDataFrame` that contains the coordinates and the predictor values for the entire study area.

What am I doing wrong here? I would also like to know what exactly happens within the scond step.

Comment: I ran it over night and get the following warning message: `Warning messages:
1: In anyDuplicated.default(new) :
  Reached total allocation of 8110Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In anyDuplicated.default(new) :
  Reached total allocation of 8110Mb: see help(memory.size)` So maybe it is a problem of memory size?